# Wordpress in Official Docker Image - sending emails won't work

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, phpmailer

I am using the official WP Docker image. Using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM wordpress:5.0.3-php7.1-apache

#install some base extensions
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
          libzip-dev \
          zip \
    && docker-php-ext-configure zip --with-libzip \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip pdo pdo_mysql
```

However, i just cant send any email from within wp. When setting up the sending of emails via PHPMail on Mailpoet i only get the Error msg:

> Error Sending Message PHP Mail works with MailPoet to
>   email@example.com | Could not instantiate mail function.

I'm going crazy on this. Can't I expect the official wp docker image to support phpmail by default?

Answer (score 2):

I beleive there are no 'out of the box' answers with official WP Docker image. But you can always use SMTP

And here are a lot of plugins which can handle it for you.

[WP SMTP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-smtp/)

[Easy WP SMTP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-wp-smtp/)

[3]: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/  *seems most popular

*Just search for any 'wp smtp' article if you have any troubles with those plugins.*